# ¿Cómo configurar idioma español en TiddlyWiki?

Tags: json, tiddlywiki

Tengo instalada la versión de TiddlyWiki 5.1.17 en servidor node.

En la pestaña Plugins del panel de control, elijo el lenguaje "Castellano (Spain)" reinicio el servidor pero sin embargo no veo los cambios.

Answer (score 0):

La anterior forma de instalar el plugin funciona para la versión de escritorio, pero no para la versión de servidor.

Para servidor node, seguir los siguientes pasos:

- Identificar plugin a instalar, los plugins se identifican por su tipo (Plugins, Temas o Idiomas), editor y título. Por ejemplo, para el idioma español el plugin `$:/languages/es-ES` se identifica como `es-ES`
- Detener el servidor si está en ejecución.
- Editar el archivo tiddlywiki.info, (ubicado en la carpeta de instalación de TiddlyWiki - esta en formato JSON) y agregar la sección `languages`, (ver abajo)
- Nota, para los plugins y temas, ubicar las secciones `plugins` y `themes`
- Agreagar las entradas correspondientes a los plugins que desea instalar. (Tener cuidado de separar los ítems con coma, pero al último ítem no colocarle)
- Reiniciar el servidor

  ```
  "plugins": [
      "tiddlywiki/codemirror"
  ],
  "themes": [
      "tiddlywiki/vanilla",
      "tiddlywiki/snowwhite"
  ],
  "languages": [
      "es-ES",
      "fr-FR",
      "en-EN"
  ]
  ```

Información:

- https://tiddlywiki.com/#Installing%20a%20plugin%20from%20the%20plugin%20library